# "Flatten" a list of case class[A] that contains lists of other case classes

Tags: scala

I have a case class `A` that contains lists of case classes B, C and D. So for example it would be in this format: `A(List[B], List[C], List[D])`. List[B], List[C] and List[D] could be empty. Is there a way to "flatten" the case class so that empty lists would be removed from it? Does this require mapping to an entirely new case class? Alternatively, is pattern matching the best way to deal with this? 
For example in the below code:

```
List(
  CombinedActions(
    List(),
    List(),
    List(D(
      Some(NYS),
      2016-04-17T22:08:09.000Z,
      Some(Growth Properties),
      Some(USE),
      Some(New York Stock Exchange))),
    CombinedActions(
      List(),
      List(),
      List(D(
        Some(CA),
        2016-04-17T22:08:09.000Z,
        Some(Growth Properties),
        Some(USE),
        Some(Toronto Stock Exchange))))))
```

I want to remove the empty `List ()` values in the CombinedActions class which has the format

```
case class CombinedCorporateActions(
  capital_changes: List[B],
  idChanges: List[C],
  IPO: List[D])
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. Can you show a sample input and desired output? And any code that you have tried so far?

Comment: Updated the post with sample desired output

Comment: I was expecting a more elegant solution than just mapping to another class.

Comment: You probably want to use a list of lists instead of a case class. That will allow you to remove empty sub-lists.